Unable to Create Redis OSS Cache in AWS due to VPC Subnet Issue
I'm trying to create a Redis OSS cache using Amazon ElastiCache in AWS, but I'm getting "Customer account VPC should have a minimum of 3 default subnets." I have set up my VPC with multiple subnets and route tables. The details of my setup are:
VPC and Subnets

VPC ID: vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Subnets:

myapp-subnet-public1-us-west-2a (10.0.0.0/20)
myapp-subnet-public2-us-west-2b (10.0.16.0/20)
myapp-subnet-public3-us-west-2c (10.0.192.0/20) (Auto-assign public IPv4 address enabled)
myapp-subnet-private1-us-west-2a (10.0.128.0/20)
myapp-subnet-private2-us-west-2b (10.0.144.0/20)
myapp-subnet-private3-us-west-2c (10.0.208.0/20)



Route Tables

myapp-rtb-public3-us-west-2c (Main Route Table)

Routes:

Destination 0.0.0.0/0 -> Target igw-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Destination 10.0.0.0/16 -> Target local


Subnets without explicit associations:

myapp-subnet-public3-us-west-2c
myapp-subnet-private3-us-west-2c




myapp-rtb-public

Routes:

Destination 0.0.0.0/0 -> Target igw-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Destination 10.0.0.0/16 -> Target local


Explicit Subnet Associations:

myapp-subnet-public1-us-west-2a
myapp-subnet-public2-us-west-2b





Steps Taken

Verified Subnet Configuration:

Ensured that the subnets have the correct CIDR blocks and are in the correct Availability Zones.
Enabled auto-assign public IPv4 address for all public subnets.
Confirmed that the subnets are available and not overlapping in CIDR range.


Configured Route Tables:

Created route tables and added routes for internet access and local VPC communication.
Ensured that the main route table (myapp-rtb-public3-us-west-2c) has routes for 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to the internet gateway and 10.0.0.0/16 pointing to local.
Associated public subnets myapp-subnet-public1-us-west-2a and myapp-subnet-public2-us-west-2b explicitly with the myapp-rtb-public route table.


Checked Subnet Associations:

Verified that the subnets are correctly associated with the appropriate route tables.
Made sure that myapp-subnet-public3-us-west-2c is in the main route table (myapp-rtb-public3-us-west-2c).
Double-checked that all public subnets are set to auto-assign public IPv4 addresses.


Renaming and Consistency:

Renamed subnets and route tables to a consistent naming convention to avoid any conflicts.
Updated references and associations after renaming to ensure consistency.


Validation:

Verified the entire setup through the AWS Management Console to ensure no discrepancies.
Reviewed all settings and configurations to confirm they align with AWS best practices.



Problem
Despite having the subnets and route tables correctly configured, I am still unable to create the Redis OSS cache and receive the error about needing a minimum of 3 default subnets. What am I missing in my setup? How can I resolve this issue and successfully create the Redis OSS cache?
Additional Information

All subnets are available and correctly associated with their respective route tables.
There are no security group or networking constraints that should interfere with the subnet availability.
The VPC is properly configured and the internet gateway is attached and routed correctly.

Any help or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!

I encountered the same error message and was able to address it by:

In the "Create Redis OSS cache" page, expand the Default settings session.
Select the "Customize default settings"
In "Connectivity", select the VPC ID that you had three subnets setup. Also make sure to check the 3 subnets in "Availability Zones".

Then you will be able to hit create button.
